# byte array allocation causing large slowdown in time-critical method

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

I'm working on a high-performance app that makes a pInvoke dll call to call winapi DeviceIoControl. DeviceIoControl requires a byte buffer.

```
        public byte[] Read(IntPtr address, int length) {
            var info = new MemOperation();
            var buf = new byte[length];

            info.Pid = Pid;

            if (address == H.pBaseCtxAddress) {
                address = (IntPtr) ((ulong) address + (ulong) KeReadModuleBase());
            }

            info.Addr = address;
            info.WriteBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            info.Size = buf.Length;


            var bytes = 0;
            if (address != IntPtr.Zero && (long) address > 0 && (long) address != 0 &&
                (long) address < 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF) {
                var res = Win32.DeviceIoControl(Handle, CtlCode(0x00000022, IOCTL_READ_MEM, 2, 0), info,
                    Marshal.SizeOf(info), buf, (uint) length, ref bytes, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            return buf;
        }
```

When running Visual Studio 2019's profiler, it lists the byte array's declaration as a hotspot.

```
            var buf = new byte[length];
```

I am not constrained to safe or managed code, so I am open for unsafe solutions for this. I have debugged the actual pInvoke call, and it's as performant as it can be. The profiler doesn't list it as a hotspot either, only the byte array allocation.

I assume this is happening due to how C# is creating the new byte array. It's my understanding C# zero's out every byte when allocating the array. Is there a way instead that I can simply select a block of free memory of n length? The Driver that this IOCTL is calling is always going to return the specified length, so having dirty memory (non-zero'd) shouldn't be an issue.

This is the DllImport I have for DeviceIoControl:

```
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
            IntPtr hDevice,
            uint IoControlCode,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)][In] object InBuffer,
            int nInBufferSize,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)][Out] object OutBuffer,
            uint nOutBufferSize,
            ref int pBytesReturned,
            IntPtr Overlapped
        );
```

Here's the full call-path for this (so you understand how I'm using the results):

Multiple threads are calling `Read<T>` which is in turn calling the function `Read` that contains the byte array allocation that's posted at the beginning of the thread. The profiler lists this allocation as a hotspot. The final GetStructure converts that byte array to a struct.

```
        public T Read<T>(IntPtr address) where T: unmanaged {
            var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            var data = Read(address, size);
            return GetStructure<T>(data);
        }

        public unsafe static T GetStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T: unmanaged {
            fixed (byte* p = bytes)
            {
                T structure = *(T*)p;
                return structure;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need a new buffer every time the function is called? Or another way to ask this: Are buffers filled with data from a previous call still needed when this call happens? (You guess why I'm asking that.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have multiple threads that are calling this function, I've updated the thread. If you see how GetStructure works, I believe this means I do need to keep that buffer for each call.

Comment: How large is length (I'm asking because once you get through this, you may end up with Large Object Heap issues if length > 85k).  Consider creating a pool of buffers and recycling them.  It takes very little time to do the actual allocation of a buffer, but the Framework guarantees that the array will be zeroed out when you get it.  That can have costs.  If you grab a buffer from a pool, it won't be zeroed out (it will likely have your old data).  You can do this dynamically so that you don't have to spend a lot of time getting the size of the buffers just right

Comment: @Flydog57 the longest length read is around 800 * 0x8 (a large array of pointers, generally 600-800 in length).

Comment: You could have the calling threads allocate their own buffer, or you could use a thread-local storage (TLS) that is then reused.

Comment: `Memory<T>` and `Span<T>` are your friends.

Comment: @jwdonahue The issue to me seems to be that it takes awhile to allocate a new buffer. So, even if the other threads created their own buffer, they'd all suffer from this as well. I want to use something like a memory pool, and request a buffer of n-length. However, I tried using `System.Buffers.MemoryPool<T>` but when I use the byte-array that I retrieve with `MemoryPool.Take`, my driver throws a blue-screen for attempting to right to a read-only block of memory. So it seems that the MemoryPool.take returns a byte[] array that's in a RO page.

Comment: @Ben Well, obviously *at some point* the data in the buffer is not needed any more; in fact when `Read<T>()` is left (because it has been parsed and a separate T has been created  from it). `Read<T>`'s caller can always use the same buffer, at least per thread.